# Language Switcher with Users

Tags: users, localization, multi-site, language

I have the following setup for a language switcher. I have Member Directory pages which are using Users (rather than Entires or Categories). How can I update this to get it working on these pages?

```
{% set langSwitcher = craft.app.sites.getAllSites() %}

<div class="flag">
 {% for lang in langSwitcher %}
 {# Set homepage as default #}
 {% set url = alias(lang.baseUrl) %}

 {# Entry is defined #}
 {% if entry is defined %}
  {# Check if that entry exists in other locale #}
  {% set otherLocaleEntry = craft.entries.siteId(lang.id).id(entry.id).one() %}
  {% if otherLocaleEntry %}
    {% set url = otherLocaleEntry.url %}
  {% endif %}

{# Category is defined #}
{% elseif category is defined %}
  {# Check if that entry exists in other locale #}
  {% set otherLocaleCat = craft.categories.siteId(lang.id).id(category.id).one() %}
  {% if otherLocaleCat %}
    {% set url = otherLocaleCat.url %}
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}

 <div {% if lang.id == currentSite.id %}class="active"{% endif %}>
  <a href="{{url}}" > <img src="/assets/images/site/flag-{{lang.name|lower}}.svg" alt="{{lang.name|upper}}"></a>
 <p class="small-hide"><a href="{{url}}" >{{lang.name|upper}}</a></p>
 </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do your directory pages just break? If so, what is the error? You can't translate users so I'm guessing you would still want to translate the UI on directory pages but stay on the current page? What is the definition for `langSwitcher`?

Comment: I don't get an error, I get re-directed to the homepage (of the language).

Code updated with definition for langSwitcher

Comment: So you want all your languages to show in the switcher but when the user chooses to change language, they stay on the user page but the UI around translates? Can you show the format of your url for a directory entry page please?

Comment: Basically they need to be redirected from http://website.com/membership/directory/1227(en) to http://website.com/ru/membership/directory/1227 (ru)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't perfect by any means and might need tweaking but to get you on your way:

Assuming that on a user page, you are doing `{% set user = ... %}` somewhere (as you would do `{% set entry = ... %}` on an entry page), You just add another clause to your if statement, after checking for category, you check for user:

```
{# User is defined #}
{% elseif user is defined %}
  {% set url = lang.baseUrl ~ 'membership/directory/' ~ craft.app.request.segments|last %}
{% endif %}
```

Or if you have set the user:

```
{# User is defined #}
{% elseif user is defined %}
  {% set url = lang.baseUrl ~ 'membership/directory/' ~ user.id %}
{% endif %}
```